# How to start startActivityForResult() from a BroadcastReceiver class?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, start-activity

My main class is a BroadcastReceiver class. I want to use startActivityForResult() from the  BroadcastReceiver class. But it is not possible to call startActivityForResult() from a BroadcastReceiver class.

**So that can i call another activity class which contain startActivityForResult(), from my main BroadcastReceiver class?**

*A **simple code** for **MainBroadcastReceiver.java**, **callActivity.java** and the **manifest.xml** will be sufficient for my query.*

I am new in android programing. So please make it as simple as possible. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Make your broadcast receiver an inner class of the activity from which you will be calling your new activity then pass Activity.this to your broadcast receiver as a context.